# Dividing data into blocks define sizes

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm pretty sure I should be using `BinLists[...]` but it doesn't behave quite as I expect. Say I have a list of data :
`Data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,...}`

I want to be able to chop this data into blocks of a certain size, e.g. 
`{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12},{..}}` for blocks of three, or,
`{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16},{...}}` for blocks of four

I try using `BinLists[Data,3]` but this seems to be out of order giving me
`{{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{9,10,11},{12,13,14},...}` rather than in the form I described above.

Is there a way to modify `BinLists[...]` in some way or an alternative that will achieve what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html)?

Comment: BinLists start counting from 0, that's why there are only 2 elements in {1,2}

Comment: @Edmund no I had not seen this fucntion, thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Partition[Data,4]
```

or

```
Partition[Data,3]
```

if you want to use `BinLists`
write

```
BinLists[data, {First@data, Last@data, 3}]
```

Comment: wonderful! Thank you!